# Is null an Object?

Tags: java, null

Is null an `Object` in Java?

Comment: No it's not, and for those who wonder why such a question, there are languages where null is indeed an object like any, for example Ruby.

Comment: In Scala, which is very meticulous about types, there is a type `Null` (a *trait*, actually) having a single instance `null`.

Comment: @JRL: Just out of curiosity, I wonder how that influences how JRuby works...  (I'm not familiar enough with that level of implementation to know for sure.)

Comment: To add to @JRL's comment - Ruby's rough equivalent to `null` is `nil`, which is an instance of [NilClass](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/NilClass.html)

Comment: Or javascript, in which `null instanceof Object` is false but `typeof(null)` returns `'object'`.  Is it an object in that case?  Who knows.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

If null were an Object, it would support the methods of `java.lang.Object` such as `equals()`. However, this is not the case - any method invocation on a null results in a `NullPointerException`.

And this is what the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1) has to say on this topic:

> There is also a special null type, the
>   type of the expression null, which has
>   no name. Because the null type has no
>   name, it is impossible to declare a
>   variable of the null type or to cast
>   to the null type. The null reference
>   is the only possible value of an
>   expression of null type. The null
>   reference can always be cast to any
>   reference type. **In practice, the
>   programmer can ignore the null type**
>   and just pretend that null is merely a
>   special literal that can be of any
>   reference type.

I think this can be boiled down to "null is special".

Comment: So an object in Java is only an object if it is equal to or subclasses `java.lang.Object`. Practically - yes. You can't create a class that is not a subclass of java.lang.Object, but I never thought about it from a more philosophical point of view

Comment: Curiously, of all things, the [API doc for `NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) makes mention of a »`null` object« … :) But then, it was also okay to talk about »null pointers« …

Comment: You said: "The null reference can always be cast to any reference type". So, can we return null(typecasted-if allowed) in a method with an object reference(return) type?

Comment: @Srichakradhar: yes, we can! Which you can find out more easily by trying it in code than by asking here.

Comment: @GeroldBroser yep! :)

Comment: "The null reference is the only possible value of an expression of null type". It is time to read the Specifications doc. :)

Comment: Please, change link to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1

Comment: Just like the square root of -1. `i` is special.

Comment: @GauravMall It's not that special. `i²`  is `-1` again. ;)

Answer (score 33):

According to the Java [spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#23953), `null` is a type that can be assigned to an object variable (as a value as noted in the comment). You cannot instantiate or create variables of this type though, you must use the literal `null` provided by the compiler.

Comment: null is a type and a value.

Comment: The `null` name is an "instance" of the `null` type, apparently.

Comment: `null` is not a variable, it's a literal: [JLS, 3.10.7. The Null Literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7)

Comment: Re "_`null` is a type that can be assigned_": 1) `null` (in code) is the _null literal_, not the _null type_ 2) Types cannot be assigned to variables in Java in general, see [JLS 4.1: "_There are \[...\] two kinds of data values that can be stored in variables \[...\]: primitive values (§4.2) and reference values (§4.3)._"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1)  It's [the null reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7) that can be assigned via the `null` literal. ...cont'd...

Comment: 3) _object_ in "_object variable_", compared to class variable, usually doesn't refer to the type but to the lifetime. When referring to the type it's usually called _variable of a reference type_ or, for short, _reference (type) variable._ I'm aware of 4 types in the Java API that expose instance/object variables (there may be more): [arrays with its `length`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3) and the subclasses of [`java.awt.geom.Point2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html).

Answer (score 29):

Absolutely not: `null instanceof Object` returns false.

Comment: And yet it is assignment compatible with all reference types.

Answer (score 13):

JRL (and others) wrote:

> No it's not, ...

As often, it depends from where you look at it, who you believe more.

According to the JLS, **yes, it is**. Especially if you rephrase the question to: „Is the `null` literal of type `Object`?”.
In addition to [JLS 4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1) cited by Michael Borgwardt above:

See [JLS 3.10.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7):

> A null literal is always of the null type.

and [JLS 4.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10):

> The subtypes of a type T are all types U such that T is a supertype of U, **and the null type.**

or [JLS 4.10.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2):

> **The direct supertypes of the null type are all reference types** other than the null type itself.

[Emphases by me.]

According to Eclipse 2019-09's compiler **it's not**:

```
true.toString();  // Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type boolean
null.toString();  // Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type null
```

According to OpenJDKs 12.0.1 `javac` **it is**:

```
true.toString();  // error: boolean cannot be dereferenced
null.toString();  // error: <null> cannot be dereferenced
```

Where the angle brackets imply that `null` is of an other than a primitive type. And according to [JLS 4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1):

> There are two kinds of types in the Java programming language: primitive types (...) and reference types (...).

if it's not the one it's the other.

---

Claudiu wrote:

> null is kind of ugly.

Au contraire, `null` is beautiful. What would you suggest as default value for a reference type variable instead? An arbitrary bit combination? Welcome to access violation or, even worse, pointer hell!

---

Joachim Sauer wrote:

> null is a type and a value.

There are actually *three* items in conjunction with *null* (see also [JLS 3.10.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7)):

1. The (otherwise unnamed) *null type*.
2. The `null` *literal*.
3. The *null reference* value. (Commonly abbreviated as *null value* or simply *null*.)

(1) Note that, according to [JLS 4.10.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2) cited above, the *null type* uses multiple inheritance not only for interfaces but for classes as well. Which we all know is not possible for us application programmers.

(2) The *null literal* might be imagined as a variable being defined as:

`JVM_global final null_type null = new null_type();`

Note also [JLS 3.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9):

> *A variety of character sequences are sometimes assumed, incorrectly, to be keywords:*

> - *`null` is not a keyword, but rather the null literal ([§3.10.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7)).*

---

### Concerning `null instanceof <any type>`

With JLS 4.10.2 in mind („the *null type* is a subtype of every type”) `null instanceof <any type>` should be supposed to evaluate to `true`, shouldn't it? At first sight, yes, but [JLS 15.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) gives the insight answer:

> [...] **the result** of the `instanceof` operator **is `true` if the value** of the *RelationalExpression* **is not `null`** [...]. **Otherwise the result is `false`**.

[Emphases by me.]

Ask yourself what makes more sense (from an application programmer's point of view):

- Giving `false` and thus indicating that a reference expression is not of a type exposed to us, i.e. indicating it's not referencing anything useful to us
- or giving `true`, thus informing us that the expression evaluates to a special reference, the *null reference*, referencing an "object" we don't know whether it even exists and which is of the special *null type* which has no name, is not exposed to us but via the *null literal*, is a subtype of any type including multiple inheritance and is to be ignored anyway? Consider also the more practical example:

  ```
     class Car implements Vehicle {  
     ...
     Vehicle car = null;
     ...
     boolean b = car instanceof Car;  // True? There's not even an instance
     ...                              // which could be of type Car.
  ```

Which also leads to:

#### Why is `instanceof` not a proper way to say something about `null`'s Object-ness?

It's called `instanceof` not `sameorsubtypeof`. That means we are comparing an instance's type with a type, not two types. Now `null` means: „There is no instance” and if there is no instance there's no instance's type. It's obvious that comparing nothing with something is supposed to lead to `false`.

Or in a "more" real world example:

- I have a real-size picture of an apple (*=reference type*) in my hands with »Big Apple« (*=reference type name*) written on it.
- There's a table (*=heap*) in front of me.
- If there is an apple (*=instance*) on the table there is a cord (*=reference*) connected to it.
- I hold the other end of this cord in my hand (*=reference variable*) .
- I trace the apple along the cord and compare it with my picture (*=instanceof*).
- If the apple is of the same size or bigger than the picture the writing »Big Apple« applies to it (*=true*).
- If it's smaller, then not (*=false*).
- If there is no apple on the table (=*no instance*) and, hence, no cord exists (*=null*) the writing doesn't apply either (*=false*). Because: Is *no* apple a big apple? No, it's not.

As Michael sums up: "null is special" indeed.

Comment: Apple and null? Aren't you afraid of a lawsuit? :)

Answer (score 12):

Null is the lack of an object.

Comment: But the null type is assignable to every reference type.

Comment: There is no "null type"; null is a specific value of non-primitive expressions (i.e. references; there is no "reference type" in Java either, to my understanding).

Comment: Tommy: JLS 4.1: "There is also a special null type, the type of the expression null, which has no name."

Comment: @TommyMcGuire Re »_there is no "reference type" in Java_« see [JLS 4.1: "_There are two kinds of types in the Java programming language: primitive types (§4.2) and reference types (§4.3)._"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1)

Answer (score 11):

No, it is not an object.

Answer (score 9):

No, it's not an instance of a Class nor a Class. It's a reference to nothing.

**Edit**: haven't read the spec so the above may not be 100% accurate.

Answer (score 6):

As explained in the chapter [4.1 The Kinds of Types and Values](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.1) of the Java Language Specification, **null is a type which has one value, the null reference** (and is represented by the literal `null`):

> There is also a special *null* type, the
>   type of the expression `null`, which has
>   no name. Because the null type has no
>   name, it is impossible to declare a
>   variable of the null type or to cast
>   to the null type. The null reference
>   is the only possible value of an
>   expression of null type. The null
>   reference can always be cast to any
>   reference type. In practice, the
>   programmer can ignore the null type
>   and just pretend that `null` is merely a
>   special literal that can be of any
>   reference type.

You might want to read about the *Null Object Pattern* (that I  don't recommend) though. See the [C2 Wiki](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?NullObject) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) for more on this pattern.

Answer (score 4):

No, is not an object as null instanceof Object will always return false also there is only one null, not one for each class.

Comment: In fact, `null instanceof <anytype>` will return `false`, too.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Java Spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html),

> There's also a special null literal
>   that can be used as a value for any
>   reference type. null may be assigned
>   to any variable, except variables of
>   primitive types. There's little you
>   can do with a null value beyond
>   testing for its presence. Therefore,
>   null is often used in programs as a
>   marker to indicate that some object is
>   unavailable.

Answer (score 4):

Java handles objects via references. Null is a breakdown of OO-ness of Java, since it drops you below OO level. No it is not an object it is a VALUE of a reference. And it has nothing to do with object paradigms, but relates to plumbing of Java, that enables objects.

Answer (score 3):

Is null an instance of `java.lang.Object`? No.

Is null an *object*? depends on the definition of "*is*".

Comment: Wrong site herein? → https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
Object foo = null;
System.out.println(foo.toString());
```

The first line shows `null` can be assigned to type `Object`, but the second line will demonstrate it is certainly not an `Object` and eventually results in a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

No ,`null` is not an object.It is a reference type and its value does not refer to any object and so there is no representation of `null` in memory.

Comment: The OP asked for (the type) `Object`, not _object_ (as in _instance of a type_). And [if one rephrases the question accordingly...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12886252/1744774)