# Why do I get a NullPointerException when comparing a String with null?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

My code is breaking on the following line with a nullpointerexception:

```
 if (stringVariable.equals(null)){
```

Previous to this statement, I declare the stringVariable and set it to a database field.

In this statement, I am trying to detect if the field had a `null` value, but unfortunately it breaks!

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're calling a method on a variable containing null. `equals()` isn't special, it will still throw a NPE.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use

```
stringVariable == null
```

To test whether `stringVariable` is `null`.

The `equals` method (and every other method) requires `stringVariable` to not be `null`.

Answer (score 17):

if `stringvariable`is already null, it doesn't exist as a `String` object anymore, so it won't even have a `.equals` method!  So in the event when `stringvariable` *is* null, what you are really doing is `null.equals(null)`, at which point you'll get the `NullPointerException` because `null` doesn't have a `.equals()` method.

Comment: While the approved comment does, in fact, help to answer the "spirit" of the OP question,(they just ask for "any thoughts") I believe this answer expands a bit more on the "why" to help future readers.

Answer (score 7):

It is never wise to call a method, be it equals() or otherwise,on a variable which may be null. That is why one usually does something like:

```
if ( var != null && var.method(something) ) {
  // var.method() was true
} else {
  // var is null or var.method is false
}
```

In your special case it would be sufficient to do

```
if (stringVariable == null) {
}
```

when working with Strings it can pay to check out [Apache Commons StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html).

It always pays to check out the apache commons libraries as they have lots of optimized utilities (for Strings, Collections, Dates and such) which tend to be better than home-written ones.

Comment: More common is when used against a string literal, and we reverse it as: `if ("true".equals(value)) {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

The equals() method does not work with null parameter.

The method needs to have an object or string as parameter.

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject)
```

*Since null is not an object.*
[Is null an Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894149/is-null-an-object).

Also refer to java 7 documentation which says that equals will give result if and only if the object passed is not null.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: The java 7 documentation does not say that. You rephrased it giving it different meaning. What is the opposite of "give result"? "give no result"? That is not the same as true/false. So `equals()` does work with a null parameter, it just cannot be called on a `null` object.