# "JOptionPane java.lang.NullPointerException" error in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, joptionpane

This is my full code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Lab5bug {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x=0;
    String str;
    for (;;)
    {
        str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a grade 0-100\n(Hit Cancel to abort)");
        if (str==null || str.equals(""))
            break;
        x = Integer.parseInt(str);
        if (x>=0 && x<=100)
            break;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Invalid grade, try again");
    }
    if (str != null  & !str.equals(""))   //<===========BUG:  NEEED TO USE && 
        //&,||.| are all lead to bug if we press Cancel.
        //str can be null it does not pass 1st condition
        //but still pass 2nd condition
        //str can be "" pass first condition but not second condition
        //and therefre it still show the message The grade is 0
        //But why 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "The grade is " + x);
}
}
```

When I run the program and press Cancel at the first dialog box, then the program returns a error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Lab5bug.main(Lab5bug.java:19)
```

I have already located the problem, at this line 
    if (str != null  & !str.equals(""))
But why only && works? I do not understand the logic behind this.

Comment: Is "str != null  & !str.equals("")" meant to have a single '&'? Looks like it should be '&&' ?

Comment: Thank you @robert, I have found the answer myself at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358019/why-do-i-get-a-nullpointerexception-when-comparing-a-string-with-null

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences in boolean operators: & vs && and | vs ||](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014535/differences-in-boolean-operators-vs-and-vs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
if (str != null & !str.equals(""))
```

with

```
if (str != null && !str.equals(""))
```

`&` stands for bitwise AND. Therefore when `str` is null, the expression `!str.equals("")` throws a `NullPointerException`. When the logical AND operator `&&` is used, the `!str.equals("")` expression won't be reached because the first condition `str != null` is false.

Comment: I already knew this but why only && works? can you explain? Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014535/differences-in-boolean-operators-vs-and-vs for more info why

Comment: @fish. When `&&` is used, the expression `str.equals("")` is not reached since `str != null` evaluates to false.

Comment: @manouti but according to this, when using between  2 boolean, & and && are the same. Also, I do not understand what's wrong with OR in this situation.

Comment: @fish. `&&` is short-circuit operator. It assumes that since `false && whatever()` will always result in `false` there is no need to invoke `whatever()` method. So if in `test1() && test2()` `test1()` will be evaluated to `false` there is no need to invoke `test2` (result will not change). `&` doesn't do this optimization and will try to test all arguments in `test1() & test2()` expression, so for `(x!=null && x.doSomething()` even it it will know that `x` is `null` it will still try to invoke `doSomething()` on this null which will throw NPE.

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo. I did not know that when you cast the method equal, you need the string to be not "null" Thanks all you guys!

Comment: @fish. `null` doesn't have any methods or fields (it isn't instance of any class), so when you are trying to access them from `null` it means that something bad happened and your code has bugs, so it needs to be stopped. That is why NPE is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

`&` does not short circuit the statement, meaning that if `str != null` is false, it still tries `str.equals("")` which would cause a NPE if `str` is null. The system naively evaluates the second part of the statement with `&` even if the first part is false.

`&&` works because it short circuits the statement, and if `str != null` is false, it breaks from the statement not evaluating the second part of the statement and avoiding the NPE; because the statement can't be true if the first value is false.

Most of the time `&&` is more desirable than `&`.

Also the same rule applies to OR, `|` and `||`. `true | throw new RuntimeException("Second part of statement was evaluated ");` will throw that exception, whereas `true || throw new RuntimeException("Second part of the statement was evaluated")` will not reach the exception because the statement is guaranteed to be true because the first part of the statement evaluates to true, so it short circuits and breaks from the statement.

Comment: so if str is null then str.equals("") will result in NPE?

Comment: Yes, you cannot run methods on null.

Comment: We avoid that with the use of `&&` though, because `if(str != null && !str.equals(""))` says if `str` is not null check if it equals "", else run code.