# Does 'null' belong to any type?

Tags: java

The code below really confused me. The output is "int array", but if I quote the second Confusing function, the output will be "Obejct". I wonder what null really means in Java.

**And also why the Confusing class is created with calling the second constructor while not the first constructor**

**Why the compiler will call that constructor as it always calls the lowest extension of a class**

```
public class Confusing {

    public Confusing(Object o){
        System.out.println("Obejct");
        if(o instanceof Object)
            System.out.println("Object");
    }

    public Confusing(int[] iArray){
        System.out.println("int array");
        if(iArray instanceof int[])
            System.out.println("Array");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Confusing(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java

Comment: Null means nothing, you can pass nothing instead of any object, but it's rarely a good idea unless the method is expecting it

Comment: Why you have to check if it is an `instanceof`? Doesn't `type hinting` already does that?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894149/is-null-an-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894149/is-null-an-object)

Comment: @user3082297 this works, because int[] extends Object so the compiler will call that constructor as it always calls the lowest extension of a class (sorry don't know how to explain this well). Now if you change the `Object` to `String` you will get an ambigious error, as int[] doesn't extend String and therefore the compiler doesn't know which constructor to call. This you can fix by casting null: `new Confusing((String) null)` or `new Confusing((int[]) null)`. I wanted to add an answer with nice formatting, but unfortunately this question was blocked...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I know how it works now, but is there anyone who can told me why the compiler will call that constructor as it always calls the lowest extension of a class.

Answer (score 3):

`null` is **not** an object, it's a *reference*, see [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1):

> There is also a special `null` type, the type of the expression `null`,
>   which has no name. Because the `null` type has no name, it is impossible
>   to declare a variable of the `null` type or to cast to the `null` type.
>   The `null` reference is the only possible value of an expression of `null`
>   type. The `null` reference can always be cast to any reference type. In
>   practice, the programmer can ignore the `null` type and just pretend
>   that `null` is merely a special literal that can be of any reference
>   type