# Why does Eclipse say that null is a primitive type?

Tags: java, eclipse, null

I wrote this line of code in Eclipse Mars for messing purposes:

```
null.toString();
```

And I got the following compiler error message:

> Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type null

Which is very strange since `null` is not a primitive type nor an object reference as explained here: [Is null an Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1894149/1065197)

So, just to be sure, I tried to compile such odd line of code using `javac` and I got this result:

> ```
> NullTest.java:3: <nulltype> cannot be dereferenced
>
>    null.toString();
>        ^  
> 1 error
> ```

Does somebody know why Eclipse would give such (IMO) misleading compiler error message?

Comment: I get the same "primitive" error message in Kepler and Luna, too, so it's not a new thing.

Comment: Sounds like an evaluation path error in ECJ. File a bug on it, which they'll ignore until Java is replaced by another language.

Comment: [Yeah, smells like a bug to me, too.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.2/org.eclipse.jdt/ui/3.8.0/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/refactoring/typeconstraints/types/TypeEnvironment.java#TypeEnvironment.0NULL)  It's been around for a long while though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the null-type is a [subtype](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10) of `Object`, it's conceivably OK to invoke `Object` methods on `null`.

However, following that logic, since the null-type is a subtype of every reference type, we should be allowed to invoke any method of any class/interface on `null`. That'll be a mess.

Syntactically, `null.toString()` should be [recognized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) as a method invocation expression at first, because `null` is a `Primary` expression. Then, to determine the class/interface to search for the method `toString`, JLS [says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1)

> ...The class or interface to search is T if T is a class or interface type, or the upper bound of T if T is a type variable
>
> It is a compile-time error if T is not a reference type.

`T` is the null-type here; it is not a class type, interface type, or type variable, therefore this step should fail.
However, does it fail because *T is not a reference type*?

Is the null-type a reference type?  JLS [says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html)

> The types ... are divided into two categories: primitive types and reference types
>
> The numeric types are ....
>
> The reference types are class types, interface types, [type variables,] and array types . [period!]
>
> **There is also a special null type**.

Depending on your parsing of the text, null-type may or may not be a reference type. That is  usually not really important; it's just a matter of categorization. But it leads to confusions, for example in this case -- the failure is because `T` is not a "proper" reference type, and the compiler deduces by mistake that it must be a primitive type then.

Comment: I think this is something Scala has done right.   The Option class.   Contains null or something or valid.

Comment: @Totoro if you refer to [`Option`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option), well there's a similar type called [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: This explanation seems more interesting and convincing for me. At least, it makes me think that Eclipse guys *forgot* that there's a null type and just assumed that if the variable is not a reference then it's a primitive and let it be. Bugs or assumptions like this happen even in the most experienced teams.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - I think the more reasonable choice is to consider null-type a reference type; I bet most people think in that way; and the JLS probably has many places where that is implied.

Comment: I don't think it's a correct reading of the spec to say that `null` is a subtype of `Object`. It's a special type, whose reference is castable to any other reference type -- but the spec doesn't ever say that it's a subtype of object. In fact, 4.3.1 describes it as "a special null reference, which refers to no object." The absence of an object is not a subtype of an object.

Comment: @yshavit -- 4.10 does say that null-type is a subtype of every type (even including primitive type? probably a bug there). The spec is very chaotic on null. I think it mixes up lots of different concepts together (to be more concise?) - empty type, null type (with one value - null), strict class/interface type (with object values; no null), loose reference type.

Comment: Say we use `!String` notation for "strict" reference type; the type does not include `null` value. The usual `String` type is actually a loose type, equivalent to `!String or null-type`; that is why `String` accepts `null` value, and null-type is a subtype of `String`

Comment: however, in `obj instanceof String` expression, `String` is used in a strict sense, and the expression is false if `obj` is null

Comment: Yeah, good point -- I missed that one sentence there. And yes, it's oddly hand-wavy about null. It's not even quite sure as to whether null is a reference type or some other, third type, which is weirdly castable to a reference type.

Answer (score -2):

There is no reason.

Usually eclipse analyze the bytecode and for some reason `null.toString()` are two bytecode-statements, a definition and a call. Because you can call `toString` only on objects, eclipse assumes the declaraion must declare a primitive.

You can write a [Bugreport](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) but think about the overhead that may come with the internationalization of the error-message.

Comment: If you talk about internationalization of the error message, I must say they're providing a misleading error message in several languages, not only in English!

Comment: But its a new message that does not exists in any other language till now. Its scut-work vs nonscientific.

Comment: Eclipse does not analyze the bytecode: it is its own compiler which analyzes the source code building the AST, then *produces* the bytecode. So your answer is misleading.