# equals method of Object class - how it works - Java

Tags: java, object, equals

I was wondering how equals method in Object class works. This is the implementation of the method.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

where its evident that equals method is using `==`.
So,now when I am comparing two objects a and b, if a happens to be null, it doesn't throw any exception. But `a.equals(b)`, throws NPE, why?

Comment: Because [null is not an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894149/is-null-an-object). Null doesn't have methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But a.equals(b), why does it throw NPE?

Because you can't invoke a method on `null` (methods are invoked by the referene variable in Java). When `a` is null, there is simply nothing to call `equals` on (*or* to de-reference). All that `Object` (non-primitive) Java variable types can hold is the value of a reference (or `null`, which by **definition** is not a value). That's why Java (pass by value), has the functionality of pass by reference. The value of `Object`(s) **are** references.

Comment: Yes, null cannot be invoked. I understod. But, I didn't understand the last line, where you said java has pass by reference functionality. I know that Java is pass by value, but could you explain the last line more.

Comment: @user2296988 When you pass an instance between methods, its' state can be modified (because it's passed by value, but the value is a reference). For example, [`Arrays.sort(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-). Arrays are `Object`(s), and it sorts a passed in array (and returns `void`). `StringBuilder` methods that allow chaining, return `this` to do so.

Comment: hmm... i got what you meant in those examples, that is ,modifying the reference value  passed in a method, without the need of return. Btw, is it the same in other OOP languages? Is null not a value in other languages as well?

Comment: @user2296988 Modifying the referent value, the reference value doesn't change (you can't modify the caller's reference). In **most** languages anyway, I don't know about ***all*** languages. Erlang, Haskell, Smalltalk, LISP or Scheme *could* have different semantics. Java does have [`Optional<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: what i meant was, when we call `Collections.sort(List<T> list)`, the method doesn't have a return value. It modifies the value that 'list'(reference variable) is referring to. Callers value is being changed here, so does the reference.

Comment: @user2296988 Yes. And what I was trying to clarify, is that a method that assigns a new reference to `list` (`list = new ArrayList<T>();`), has created a new `list` locally - but the caller's `list` will not change. And yes, the instance being refered to is the *referent*.

Answer (score 1):

When you call method on null object, it even doesn't call the method but gives null pointer error on same movement.
Same is applicable to equals.

When invoke `a.equals(b)`;

It will give null pointer exception as you are calling equals on a which is null.

For example, if you create method blank.

```
public Class MyClass{
    public voidblank() {

    }
}
```

and now even if you call blank on null object it will give you null pointer, nothing to do with method implementation.

```
MyClass a = null;
a.blank();
```

This will also give null pointer as a is null.

Answer (score 0):

a.equals(b) throws null pointer exception because a is null, so when you try to call the instance method on a null object it gives a null pointer exception. For more information please refer to the documentation below for null pointer exception.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html

For these types of situation you should first check whether a is null and then should use the method on this object.

```
if(a != null) {
    a.equals(b);
}
```